# Android NDK LLVM cannot find C libraries stdio.h

Tags: android-ndk

I have a bunch of C code (legacy) which I'm attempting to compile with LLVM (cross-compile to ARM64). Using this relatively simple compile command:

```
$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clan -o my_c_app.o my_c_app.c
```

Yields:

```
fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
```

I'm on a M1 Mac. I'm using Android NDK's clang (vs default Mac) since I wanna standardize the compiler (Android NDK is available on multiple platforms) and cross-compile to Android anyway. Looking at where the toolchain is installed, I don't see any of the standard C headers. Does...ANDROID_NDK LLVM support C (not C++)?

And I assume I need to point LLVM to the right include directories in the NDK toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give clang a `-target`. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md